# I want to take only int Input and output all numbers except 42

Tags: java

I want to  take small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits **BUT i want to output all the numbers before reading 42 directly to output at once written in Java Language**

`example :`
`Input:`
`1`
`2`
`88`
`42`
`99`

`Output:`
`1`
`2`
`88`

I have written following program but it prints 42 which should not be the case. can anyone guide me that how to exclude 42 from writting using Java 8 features to make it more optimized :

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Life {

    public static void main(String... kl) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        while (num != 42) {
            num = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("number is: " + num);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger and you will soon see what the problem is.

Comment: In the while loop but it is printing 42 and only last input also but not all numbers..how can i print all numbers except 42

Comment: Imagine that your program has the input "1 42". Make a list of each thing it does in sequence and add it to your question.

Comment: Since the 42 check is in the `while` loop, the loop will **stop** when encountering a 42. To **skip**, use an `if` statement.

Comment: It should take at least some inputs after 42

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to get simultaneously response, use below code.

```java
public class Life {
    public static void main(String... kl) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        int num;
        while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 42) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}
```

Input / Output:

```
Enter numbers
1
1
2
2
88
88
42
Completed
```

If you prefer to output at the end of the reading values, you can store values into a list and print all of them at the end.

```java
public class Life {
    public static void main(String... kl) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        int num;
        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 42) {
            input.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}
```

Input / Output:

```
Enter numbers
1
88 
44
42
[1, 88, 44]
Completed
```

Also, you can input all numbers between spaces in a single line.

Input / Output:

```
Enter numbers
1 2 88 42 88
[1, 2, 88]
Completed
```

Answer (score -1):

You should ask for input and check at the same time. Remove `nextInt()` from before the loop. Something like this should work:

```
while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 42) 
    System.out.println("number is: "+num)
```

Just change the loop like above and rest of the code is fine. I am not talking about more efficient solution as you are in learning phase.

Comment: What happens the first time through the loop, when there is no `num`?

Comment: @tgdavies if you see the code thoroughly, OP is asking for `num` before the loop.

Comment: And what if that number is 42?

Comment: Yup you are right, we should add a check for this too